# Can I retrieve a ViewModel from an ActionResult?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewmodel, actionresult

Trying to avoid repetition here. I have an action in a base class controller which I am not allowed to modify. I'd like my action to do some checks, call the base class action, and modify the result in some way before rendering. But part of what I need to do involves modifying some properties of the `ViewModel`, and the base class returns an `ActionResult`. I see no way to get the `ViewModel` from the `ActionResult`, and so I may have to write a custom method, most of which would just mimic what the base class is doing. I'd strongly prefer not to do this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's because `ActionResult` is a fairly high-level base class.  Try casting it to the appropriate subtype, such as `ViewResult`.

Quick sample code:

```
    public ActionResult WrapperAction()
    {
        // do your initial stuff


        // call your base controller action and cast the result
        // it would be safer to test for various result types and handle accordingly
        ViewResult result = (ViewResult)base.SomeAction();

        object model = result.ViewData.Model;

        // do something with the model

        return result;
    }
```